# Is there a way to make nginx only ask for a PEM pass phrase a single time?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I use nginx as a simple SSL proxy and have 7 virtual hosts configured (plus a default host). Interestingly, whenever I restart the server, I have to enter the PEM pass phrase for my private key **20**(!) times, which gets old really quick. The number of prompts has increased with the number of hosts defined.

I have set up SSL-enabled hosts with Apache in the past, and there I only had to enter the pass phrase for every key a single time, no matter how many virtual hosts were using that key.

Is there any possibility to make nginx behave more like apache in this regard and only ask once for the same pass phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your only options for nginx are:

1. Enter the passphrase each time you restart, for each virtualhost
2. Remove the passphrase from the private key

Not great options, obviously, but AFAIK that's all you can do in this scenario (short of scripting but that basically ends up at a level of security close to #2).